# Is there a public & concrete instance of Nashorn's ScriptObjectMirror available in Java?

Tags: java, nashorn

I'm basically wanting to go:

```
ScriptObjectMirror myObj = new ConcreteScriptObjectMirror();
```

And then invoke some JS like this, where `myObj` is the parameter:

```
function myJSFunc(param) { 
    with(param) { 
        return paramProperty; 
    } 
}
```

I'm doing that now, but Nashorn is complaining:

> TypeError: Cannot apply "with" to non script object

So the Java object I pass in needs to be an instance of ScriptObjectMirror.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and just in case you haven't found your answer yet. I think the following snippet of code may contain what you want. I'm using `javax.script.SimpleBindings` to pass the object to the JavaScript function.

```
import javax.script.Compilable;
import javax.script.CompiledScript;
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.SimpleBindings;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        String result = demo.execute();
        System.out.println("full name is " + result);
    }

    public String execute() throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        final ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        final Compilable compilable = (Compilable) engine;
        final Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

        final String statement = "function fetch(values) { return values['first_name'] + ' ' + values['last_name']; };";
        final CompiledScript compiled = compilable.compile(statement);

        compiled.eval();

        SimpleBindings test = new SimpleBindings();
        test.put("first_name", "John");
        test.put("last_name", "Doe");

        FullName fullName = invocable.getInterface(FullName.class);
        return fullName.fetch(test);
    }

    public interface FullName {
      String fetch(SimpleBindings values);
    }
}
```

IMHO, Nashorn documentation is pretty bad right now, so I hope that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since ScriptObjectMirror is final, you cannot extend from this class. ScriptObjectMirror is used by the Nashorn Engine to pass javascript objects to the Java side, not the other way around.

When invoking javascript functions from java code you can just pass any arbitrary java object to the function:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(new FileReader("myScript.js"));

Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("myJSFunc", "Peter Parker");
System.out.println(result);
```

See this article for more examples: http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/

Comment: Nashorn won't accept an arbitrary Java object in a JS "with" though. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got time to test this right now, but at the point where you pass myObj to the Nashorn engine, try using Java.from(foo).

So in your example you may be able to do:

```
function myJSFunc(param) { 
    with(Java.from(param)) { 
        return paramProperty; 
    } 
}
```

It may be the case that you are passing a Java Object (ScriptObjectMirror) when this is a wrapper for your JavaScript object, calling Java.from() will unwrap this for you.

some explanation here:
https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions (search for java.from)